# Get post from CPT with same categoryname as the title

Tags: php, wordpress, post, categories

I'm working on a page where I want to show posts (custom post type) from a category which have the same categoryname as the title of the post.

I'm still learning, that's Why I hope you guys could help me out. :)

What I have:

- CPT named 'shoes'
- CPT categories: sneakers, boots, sportshoes
- CPT named 'articles'
- CPT categories: sneakers, boots, sportshoes

On the page ~/sneakers/ (from CPT 'shoes') I want to show articles from the category 'sneakers'.

This what I have till now:

```
global $post;
$cat_ID = array();
$categories = get_the_category();
foreach($categories as $category) {
    array_push($cat_ID,$category->cat_ID);
}

$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => '[THE_TITLE]',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'category__in' => $cat_ID
);

$cat_posts = get_posts($args);
if ($cat_posts) {
    foreach ($cat_posts as $cat_post) {
?>

<li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($cat_post->ID); ?>"><?php echo $cat_post->post_title; ?></a></li>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: This 'sneakers' ... etc. they are default “category” taxonomies or they are custom taxonomies attached to CPT?

Comment: those are default taxonomies

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where you want to show this articles - on page template, on single post template `http://site/shoes/shoe1`, on category template `http://site/category/sneakers/`, on custom-post template `http://site/shoes/`, etc. Because you can apply different solution depending on that.

Comment: On single-shoes.php named 'sneakers' (http://site/sneakers) I want to show all posts from 'articles' from the category 'sneakers'. It's difficult to explain, but I'm trying my best. Thanks for helping understanding the question!

Answer (score 0):

OK, based on the question and the following explanation:

We are in the `single-shoes.php` where the information for single shoe is shown.

We want to grab and display the information about `articles` custom post type, and this articles must be in specific category, which name is = `post_title`.

If this is the case you can do the following:

1. We want our posts to be from `articles` custom post type so we must put `'post_type' => 'articles'`in the `$args` array.
2. We want returned post to be in category, which name = `post_title`, so we must put `'category_name' => get_the_title()` into `$args`

The code is:

```php
    <?php

    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_type' => 'articles',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'category_name' => get_the_title()
    );

    $articles = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $articles->have_posts() ) :
        while( $articles->have_posts() ) : $articles->the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></li>
    <?php
        endwhile;
        endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

**P.S.** I'm still a little confused from the category name and still not sure that I understood correctly how this value is taken, however, if you can grab this value, the query is provided above.